# Attaching special css Styles for IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

If I add the following code in the  of the website Do I have to copy ALL the styles in the "ie6.css" or just in that file I will have to add the exceptions for fix particularly for IE6???

So by this, I will have "styles.css" that has all the styles for all the browsers + "ie6.css" will have JUST the fixes for IE6 (and not all the styles)

Or should I copy all the code in the ie6.css??

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks!!

Comment: user194076 has answered the question, but I would recommend not using a separate stylesheet. Rather, check this link: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 2):

Only those that are particular fix. No need to replace all the code. This statement says that it will ADD the following stylesheet if it is an IE6 (or lower).

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules are applied in the order listed, so generally you'll want to put IE6 fixes in a file after your main one. Only additions and adjustments to previous rules need to be included in the new file.